# Node.js I can't resolve TXT record

Tags: node.js, dns

I have an question about dns.resolveTxt.
https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolvetxt_hostname_callback

Basically I can resolve TXT record, but for specific DNS zone, I can't resolve TXT record. For example, microsoft.com and so on.
I wrote the following code.

```
var dns = require('dns');
dns.resolveTxt('microsoft.com', (err, record) => {
 console.log(record);
});
```

Does any one know the issue?

Comment: "I can't resolve" what does that mean? You get empty response? An error? Please give details. Note that "microsoft.com TXT" query results now in a 933 bytes packet, so if the library or something in the path does not implement EDNS or TCP DNS queries, you will get problems as you are over 512 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as dns from "dns";

dns.resolveTxt('microsoft.com', (err, addresses) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(addresses));
});
```

outputs

```
[["v=spf1 include:_spf-a.microsoft.com include:_spf-b.microsoft.com include:_spf-c.microsoft.com include:_spf-ssg-a.microsoft.com include:spf-a.hotmail.com include:_spf1-meo.microsoft.com -all"],["d365mktkey=3uc1cf82cpv750lzk70v9bvf2"]
,["adobe-idp-site-verification=8aa35c528af5d72beb19b1bd3ed9b86d87ea7f24b2ba3c99ffcd00c27e9d809c"],["fg2t0gov9424p2tdcuo94goe9j"],["apple-domain-verification=0gMeaYyYy6GLViGo"],["d365mktkey=4d8bnycx40fy3581petta4gsf"],["docusign=d5a3737
c-c23c-4bd0-9095-d2ff621f2840"],["adobe-sign-verification=c1fea9b4cdd4df0d5778517f29e0934"],["google-site-verification=Zv1IvEEZg4N9wbEXpBSSyAiIjDyyB3S-fzfFClb7D1E"],["google-site-verification=8-zFCaUXhhPcvN29EVw2RvtASDCaDPQ02L1HJ8Om8I0
"],["google-site-verification=pjPOauSPcrfXOZS9jnPPa5axowcHGCDAl1_86dCqFpk"],["google-site-verification=1TeK8q0OziFl4T1tF-QR65JkzHZ1rcdgNccDFp78iTk"],["8RPDXjBzBS9tu7Pbysu7qCACrwXPoDV8ZtLfthTnC4y9VJFLd84it5sQlEITgSLJ4KOIA8pBZxmyvPujuUvh
Og=="],["docusign=52998482-393d-46f7-95d4-15ac6509bfdd"],["facebook-domain-verification=fwzwhbbzwmg5fzgotc2go51olc3566"]]
```

So, clearly seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is DNS results over 512 bytes long.  As near as I can tell, Node's [dns.resolve* functions](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/dns.html#dns_implementation_considerations) do not support [EDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_Mechanisms_for_DNS), which allows up to 4096 byte responses, at least as of Node 14.  Given this code:

```
const { Resolver } = require('dns');
const dns = new Resolver();
dns.resolveTxt(process.argv[2], (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

I get this result:

```
$ node dns-test2.js google.com
Error: queryTxt ESERVFAIL google.com
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:206:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ESERVFAIL',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'google.com'
}
```

And you can see that dig returns 715 bytes for the same query:

```
$ dig TXT google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> TXT google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32543
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 9, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             30      IN      TXT     "google-site-verification=TV9-DBe4R80X4v0M4U_bd_J9cpOJM0nikft0jAgjmsQ"
google.com.             30      IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
google.com.             30      IN      TXT     "docusign=1b0a6754-49b1-4db5-8540-d2c12664b289"
google.com.             30      IN      TXT     "globalsign-smime-dv=CDYX+XFHUw2wml6/Gb8+59BsH31KzUr6c1l2BPvqKX8="
google.com.             30      IN      TXT     "google-site-verification=wD8N7i1JTNTkezJ49swvWW48f8_9xveREV4oB-0Hf5o"
google.com.             30      IN      TXT     "facebook-domain-verification=22rm551cu4k0ab0bxsw536tlds4h95"
google.com.             30      IN      TXT     "docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e"
google.com.             30      IN      TXT     "apple-domain-verification=30afIBcvSuDV2PLX"
google.com.             30      IN      TXT     "MS=E4A68B9AB2BB9670BCE15412F62916164C0B20BB"

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.10#53(10.0.0.10)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep 10 21:02:16 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 715
```

Running tcpdump, I see that the node query does not include the UDPsize=4096 option:

```
TXT? google.com. (28)
```

Whereas the dig request does:

```
TXT? google.com. ar: . OPT UDPsize=4096 (39)
```

A similar query for a TXT record that only returns 244 bytes works fine:

```
$ node dns-test2.js  partechgss.com
[
  [ 'ryb3spm2r33rtxl189nqs5n41xxrzmlz' ],
  [ 'v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all' ],
  [ 'MS=ms32721923' ],
  [ 'MS=ms56152555' ]
]
$ dig TXT partechgss.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> TXT partechgss.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56392
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;partechgss.com.                        IN      TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
partechgss.com.         30      IN      TXT     "MS=ms56152555"
partechgss.com.         30      IN      TXT     "MS=ms32721923"
partechgss.com.         30      IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
partechgss.com.         30      IN      TXT     "ryb3spm2r33rtxl189nqs5n41xxrzmlz"

;; Query time: 14 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.10#53(10.0.0.10)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep 10 21:15:21 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 244
```

Unfortunately, having identified the problem, I have yet to find a solution.  I've opened a [bug report](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40076) against the node.js project on github.